# AVRO ENUM within an array: Not a union runtime exception

Tags: java, enums, avro

I'm trying to populate an enum within an AVRO record in JAVA. Maven plugin usage was causing other issues so I decided to use GenericRecordBuilder. The AVRO record in question (only part of the schema shown that's causing me issues):

```
        {
            "name": "allocs",
            "type": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "record",
                    "name": "Allocs",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "name": "allocAmt",
                            "type": "double"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "allocType",
                            "type": {
                                "type": "enum",
                                "name": "AllocationType",
                                "symbols": [
                                    "STANDARD",
                                    "OTHER"
                                ]
                            },
                            "doc": "Contains allowed payment allocation types."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "doc": "Payment allocation array contains allocation type and amount"
        }
```

Here's the most recent iteration that allows me to add `allocAmt` but creation of `allocType` is throwing an error:

```
org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not a union: {"type":"enum","name":"AllocationType","symbols":["STANDARD","OTHER"]}
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
//payLoadSchema is the entire schema within which allocs resides
Schema paymentAllocationsSchema = payLoadSchema.getField("allocs").schema().getElementType();
List<GenericRecord> allocations = new ArrayList<>();
GenericRecord allocation = new GenericData.Record(paymentAllocationsSchema);
allocation.put("allocAmt", 100.01);

// **LINE THROWING THE ERROR I PASTED ABOVE**:
GenericData.EnumSymbol paymentAllocEnum = new GenericData.EnumSymbol(paymentAllocationsSchema.getField("allocType").schema().getTypes().get(1),"STANDARD"); 

//Adding enum to record
allocation.put("allocType", paymentAllocEnum);
//Adding record to list
allocations.add(allocation);
```

I know the exception clearly states that I'm trying to add an ENUM as a UNION but I'm not sure how to correctly create the ENUM. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out and am posting here in case someone else finds this useful. Instead of using

```
// **LINE THROWING THE ERROR I PASTED ABOVE**:
GenericData.EnumSymbol paymentAllocEnum = new GenericData.EnumSymbol(paymentAllocationsSchema.getField("allocType").schema().getTypes().get(1),"STANDARD"); 
//Adding enum to record
allocation.put("allocType", paymentAllocEnum);
```

First grab the allocationEnum from schema:

```
Schema allocationEnum = paymentAllocationsSchema.getField("allocType").schema();
```

Next, add the desired ENUM value to the allocation record:

```
allocation.put("allocType", new GenericData.EnumSymbol(allocationEnum,"STANDARD"));
```